# How do I add an Apple ID Account on XCode 4.6.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I'm trying to add a new Apple ID Account to XCode 4.6.3.

> The instructions are to open the preferences dialog and click the
>   Accounts tab.

But there is no such tab in my XCode.

What do I do now?

Comment: why using xcode 4.6.3 it is not support iOS 7

Comment: In the little time I've got to develop this app on my spare time, I'm trying not to spend too much of it upgrading tools and OS and what-not.

Comment: @RogerWernersson as of tomorrow (1st of february) you will only be able to submit app build with the iOS 7 SDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My recommendation upgrade to `xcode 5` as of tomorrow (1st of February 2014) all apps built and submitted to the app store must be done using at least `xcode 5` this was announced by Apple on December 17, 2013 here https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172013a

> Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be optimized for iOS 7.

Once you have upgrade all you need to do is Open the `xcode 5 IDE` >> `Preferences...` >> `Accounts` tab >> On the left hand side you will see `Apple IDs` and a `+` at the bottom select the `+` >> `Add Apple ID...` >> enter your `Apple ID` and `Password` click `Add`. The account should know be added.

Comment: Although I can't upgrade my MacBook. It is too old, aparently. Apple won't let me upgrade it from OSX 1.7 to 1.9, and XCode 5 only works for OSX 1.9. I have to buy a new Mac. :-(

Comment: @RogerWernersson Xcode 5.0.2 (and the upcoming 5.1) runs under OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion). You don't (yet) need Mavericks (10.9).

Answer (score 1):

> What do I do now?

Accounts tab is only available in Xcode 5.0 or above. I suggest you to upgrade xcode .It will make your life easier for configuring Apple IDs.