# Xcode -2 developer accounts?

Tags: xcode

My `Xcode`is registered under our developer account which is a company developer account.
I have to upload an app from that same `Xcode`, for another company's developer account.

I just got lost in the details, expect from setting the `code signing` and the `bundle name`, what file do I have to import to be able to keep both developer accounts on this mac? (Xcode)
Just import their provisioning development and distribution files into Xcode? Or do I need to do something else with the certificates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add as many as developer accounts in your Xcode, it won't have any issue. Whatever the profiles is created that can be download manually (or automatically). Once you're done you need to provide an exact bundle identifier which is associated with a particular account. In most of the cases, Xcode will tell you to select correct Team + Provision Profile (will be visible automatically). You're good to go with that.

References:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21481203/1603234

Comment: According to the link you provided, its enough to just add the account under Xcode accounts manager, so its not so clear to me from your answer- what else should you do ? (the other account is not visible automatically when you try to select account). What exactly are the steps I need to take ?